# How to control access to SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

I am developing an application that should use a database. System is very simple that I will try with a file based database system, however, I have found a subject that is very critical for SQLite.

Currently, if any person knows that the application database is SQLite, he can open a SQLite Manager and see database content and eventually to change data. Is it possible to avoid that in SQLite?

Comment: Can't this be performed at the system level?  Change the database file's ownership to the account that the application runs under, and restrict read/write access to the owner.  On a gnu system that would be `chown` and `chmod`.

Comment: That is not possible. This is Windows PC and any user will have access to the machine where the application will run on. The appication will consist on 2 parts. A windows service that will run under LocalSystem account and a Windows forms application that will run under the current logged in user. I cannot know previously if current logged in user is a machine Administrator. In most cases, he will be.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ordinary filesystem security to prevent unauthorized access to the file.  The Windows Service, running under its system-account, owns the file and performs all access to it on behalf of the forms-application.

However, having said that, "y'know, Microsoft *SQL Server* is pretty darned good in this case," and you can get a single-user version of it for free.  (And the full product doesn't cost *that* much ...)  They created an excellent, high-performance implementation, complete with a security model, and their server uses the techniques I have just described to secure the underlying files.  It will then be very, very easy to direct the forms-application to that database.

"When in Rome, do as the Romans do."

Comment: As I said, the system is very simple that I don't want to install a database engine to accomplish this task. SQL Server needs to install a very big database engine, That is what I want to avoid. Even if I use Express Edition or LocalDb solution, I need to install a full product which installer is several MB big.

Comment: Yup. Just be sure that you're not "re-inventing a wheel."  If data security is an important consideration, the use of SQLite might be contra-indicated.

Comment: That is what I needed to know. If SQLite does not provide such a security, I will need to opt for another solution.

Comment: A better way to think of it is, "since an SQLite database is *a file,"* and since the SQLite engine *directly reads and writes* that file," you can't realistically prevent the user from tearing the file apart if he can get his hands on it.  *"Possession is the greater part of security."* And my concern is, if you put all that stuff into a Windows Service, as you basically *will* have to do ... well ... "you just invented 'an SQL Server,' the *hard* way." ### (Incidentally, logic that does this, for SQLite, *can be found.* You don't have to (re-)invent it, if it *was* appropriate.)

Comment: Invented SQL Server? you are wrong. Maybe you misunderstood. I am not developing a SQLite manager... I am not so crazy to do something like that, I am developing a Windows service that just reads a transaction from a biometric device and store it in the database. Can you believe now that installing a full database engine is a waste of resouces? I have even thought of creating my own database, however,  I will need to create my own access modules as well, By following your own principle, I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Maybe I could end in using MS Access, even when I hate that database.

Comment: My point is that you're going to have to construct that service to provide *all* access to the database, if you need to secure it. SQLite works through direct file access, which you can't allow.  Your service must therefore be able to execute queries and to provide results to your form-app.  And *that,* in my humble, is "an SQL(ite) Server." You have *many* options available to you. Choose carefully, and good luck!